# Checking to see if this Javascript code is 'DRY' or inefficient

Tags: javascript, palindrome

I did a JS exercise where I needed to create a palindrome from a string of numbers. It works but I'm sure there is a much more concise way of accomplishing this.

direction from edabit.com:

> A number may not be a palindrome, but it's descendant can be. A number's direct child is created by summing each pair of adjacent digits to create the digits of the next number. Create a function that returns true if the number itself is a palindrome or any of its descendants down to 2 digits

```
function palindromeDescendant(input) {

  let newStr = input;
  let newRevStr = (""+input).split('').reverse().join('');

  checkEquality(newStr, newRevStr);

  function checkEquality(a, b) {

    if (a != b && (""+a).split('').length >= 2) {
      sumPair(a);
    } else if (a != b) {
        result = `${false}: ${a}`;
    } else {
      result = `${true}: ${a}`;
    }
  }

  function sumPair(nums) {
    const a = (""+nums).split('').map(Number);
    let b = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < a.length -1; i++) {
      b.push(a[i] + a[i + 1]);
      i++
    }
    newStr = b.join('');
    newRevStr = newStr.split('').reverse().join('');
    checkEquality(newStr, newRevStr);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: If the function works and you're looking for suggestions for better ways to write it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place to post.

Comment: The code is obviously DRY. Where do you see any repeated code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because code reviews don't belong on Stack Overflow. It should be posted at: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Your `result` is an implicit global, which is bad practice. When run in strict mode, your script would throw the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: result is not defined

There are a lot of places where you use `(""+value).split('')`, so that could be moved into a reusable function.

`newStr` is actually a number initially, not a string. Reassigning different types to a single variable is bad for two reasons: It is confusing to programmers reading your code, and also deoptimizes your code because of the inconsistency of the variable's type.

Your `checkEquality()` does not do what it claims. In addition to checking equality, it also checks if the length of the value in string form is greater than or equal to 2. You should make sure that when you write functions, what they actually do aligns with the intent their name suggests.

Finally, your `sumPair()` could be slightly improved by only incrementing `i` in the `for` statement for readability (This is what led to my initial confusion with your implementation and the comment about "unbounded growth").

Putting all that together, you could write an implementation that looks like the following:

```js
function toStringArray (value) {
  return value.toString().split('');
}

function reverseString (value) {
  return value.split('').reverse().join('');
}

function sumPairs (value) {
  const array = toStringArray(value).map(Number);
  const pairs = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i += 2) {
    pairs.push(array[i] + array[i + 1]);
  }

  return pairs.join('');
}

function palindromeDescendant (value) {
  const forward = value.toString();
  const reverse = reverseString(forward);

  // this is only here to demonstrate recursion in output
  console.log(forward);

  if (forward === reverse) return true;

  const descendant = sumPairs(value);

  return descendant.length >= 2 && palindromeDescendant(descendant);
}

console.log(palindromeDescendant(11211230));
```

Comment: much appreciated

Comment: About the unbounded growth, the problem calls for each pair to be summed like this: 11211230 ➞ 2333 ➞ 56 ➞ 11 so an even number of digits need to be  used when calling the function

Comment: The challenge I was trying to do calls for arguments with an even amount of digits only and to add them the way I specified. My program is doing this. I checked it with all of their examples and got the same results

Comment: @JeffS thank you for the clarification, I just missed where you called `i++` in the body of the `for` loop, so I've updated my suggestion for improving its readability.